# Dead lock pthread C++ with signaling

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, deadlock

I need 2 threads: **TC** and **TS**, such that they are composed in two main sections each accessing shared data and the threads must to be synchronized. The synchronization should be like this:
[image: synchronization]

The red codes are working with shared data `U`, but `get U` can be placed before the dashed rectangle on the `TS` thread, riht side. 
The `Xcurrent` can be in `TC` or in `TS` the tasks, but is a shared hardware with `send Ucurrent` and `get` must be right after `send` was finished.

A **dead lock** appears and I can't figure out an elegant solution.
Thread TS:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>        /* printf, scanf, NULL */
> #include <stdlib.h>     /* malloc, free, rand */
>
> #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
> #include <math.h>
> #include <windows.h>
>
> #include <pthread.h>
> #include <time.h>
>
> // CRLT-C var
> static int stop = 0;
>
> // TIMEING vars
> __int64 frequencyT, startT, endT = 0;
> double baseAngleLast;
> double pendulAngleLast;
>
> // THREADING vars
> bool startedS = false, Usent = false;
> double * Ucmd;
> pthread_mutex_t mutexU = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
> pthread_mutex_t mutexBoard = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
> unsigned int Ulenght = 6;
> pthread_cond_t signal_to_read_state = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
> pthread_cond_t signal_to_read_cmd = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
> DWORD sleepTime = 30; // in milliseconds
> int currentState = 3;
>
>
> void *sendingCMD(void * )
> {
>   double * U_tmp;
>   U_tmp = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*Ulenght);
>
>   startedS = true;
>   printf("Sin\n");
>
>   while (stop == 0)
>   {
>       printf("Smu-\n");
>       //get U
>       pthread_mutex_lock( &mutexU );  
>       printf("Smu..\n");
>       pthread_cond_wait(&signal_to_read_cmd, &mutexU);
>       memcpy(U_tmp,Ucmd,sizeof(double)*Ulenght);
>       pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutexU );
>       printf("Smu+\n");
>
>       pthread_mutex_lock( &mutexBoard );
>       for (unsigned int i = 0; i<Ulenght; i++)
>       {   
>           //send CMD signal           
>           printf("%f ", U_tmp[i]);            
>           if (i == Ulenght -1) printf("\n");
>       }
>           Sleep(sleepTime);           // miliseconds 
>       currentState = currentState + 1;
>       pthread_cond_signal(&signal_to_read_state);
>       pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutexBoard );
>       printf("Smb\n");
>   }
>   printf("Task S terminated. \n");
>   return (NULL);
> }
>
>
> void *computingU(void *)
> {
>   double * U_tmp;
>   U_tmp = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*Ulenght);
>   int currentStateTMP =0;
>   bool fisrtLoop = true;  
>
>   printf("Uin\n");
>
>   while (stop == 0)
>   {       
>       printf("Umb- \n");
>       // get  current state       
>       pthread_mutex_lock( &mutexBoard );      
>       if (!fisrtLoop) 
>       {
>           printf("UmbFalse \n");
>           pthread_cond_wait(&signal_to_read_state, &mutexBoard);
>       }
>       else
>       {       
>           printf("UmbTrue \n");
>           fisrtLoop=false;
>       }
>       currentStateTMP =currentState;      
>       pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutexBoard );
>
>       printf("Umb+ \n");
>
>       pthread_mutex_lock( &mutexU );      
>
>       for (unsigned int i=0;i<Ulenght;i++)
>       {       
>           Ucmd[i] = Ucmd[i]+ (double)currentStateTMP/i;
>       }       
>       pthread_cond_signal(&signal_to_read_cmd);
>       pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutexU );    
>       printf("Umu\n");
>   }
>   return (NULL);
> }
>
>
> void signal_handler(int signal)
> {
>   stop = 1;
> }
>
>
> int main(int argc, char* argv[])
> {
>       //initializing output buffer to 0[V]
>       Ucmd= (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*Ulenght);
>       for (unsigned int i=0;i<Ulenght;i++) 
>           Ucmd[i] = 0;
>
>   //init threads 
>       int rc1, rc2;   
>
>       pthread_t threadU, threadS;
>       /* Create independent threads each of which will execute functionC */
>       if( (rc1=pthread_create( &threadU, NULL, &computingU, NULL)) )   {
>           printf("ThreadU creation failed: %d\n", rc1);
>       }
>
>       if( (rc2=pthread_create( &threadS, NULL, &sendingCMD, NULL)) )
>       {
>           printf("ThreadS creation failed: %d\n", rc2);
>       }
>
>       while (stop == 0);
>       printf("Main terminated, closing board in 10ms. \n");
>       Sleep(10);
>
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

The blocking appears at:
**TC** at `pthread_cond_wait(&signal_to_read_state, &mutexBoard);`
**TS** at `pthread_cond_wait(&signal_to_read_cmd, &mutexU);`

btw why dose not recognize stackoverflow the code segment I pasted above in case i copy paste from a VS2010?

Comment: Can you tell us where the threads are blocked when deadlock occurs?

Comment: in the main thread, `while (stop==0);` is just waste of CPU cycles and power. If the main thread has nothing to do until worker threads complete, it should call pthread_join() on these other threads.

Comment: that is for a stop flag, so I can shut down the hardware correctly with a CRTL-C. is there an other solution for this?

Comment: You need to tell us where both threads are at the point of dead-lock.

Comment: `locking appears at while (!startedS); in TU` It is possible that compiler is optimizing this out, as it can't see that `startedS` will change. Why you just don't start `TU` from `TS` if it is important for you that thread `TU` is started after `TS`?

Comment: Blocking appears at `while (!startedS);` in `TU`. So I can't wait with `TU` that `TS` to be started.

Comment: If the stop flag is set in a signal handler, it's sufficient for the worker threads to read this flag and exit their thread functions. The main thread would be blocked in pthread_join() until worker threads complete, and exit after that.

Comment: If I take out the `while(!startedS)` then it blocks like:
`TU` at `pthread_mutex_lock( &mutexBoard );` and `TS` at `pthread_mutex_lock( &mutexU );` but only in some cases after some loops.

Like `TS` first `mutexU` does not get the signal from `TU` while `TU` already sent it and waits for the signal from `TS` at `mutexB`

Comment: Just as @NemanjaBoric said. Make startedS volatile, so the compiler won't optimize it out.

Comment: Post a complete example that can be compiled and run.

Comment: Code included, with dead block stages of tasks. This happens only in some cases, not all the time.

Comment: At a glance, seems like a race condition: Other thread does cond signal when other is not waiting, and they go out of sync. I mean, if both are cond waiting at the same time, this has to have happened, right?

Comment: Seems like that, also it is not doing what I wanted from it...

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov a better solution for the stop flag would be to create a pipe() or socketpair() at startup, and have the main thread select() on one of the sockets for ready-for-ready.  Then have your signal handler write() a byte to the other socket; that will cause the main thread to wake up from select() and go away (it should still call pthread_join() on the other threads before exiting though, to avoid potential race conditions during process cleanup)